# Function returning the contents of an object

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code:

```
function return_list_node(v,r)
 {
 return {value: v, pointer: r};
 }
console.log(return_list_node(10,return_list_node(20,null)));
```

I expected it to return `{value: 10, pointer: {value: 20, pointer: null}}`. Instead, the function returns `Object {value: 10, pointer: Object}`.

I know that it is not a console.log issue as I watched the execution of the code in my debugger - and the return value was indeed an object type.

I have tried other methods, as:

```
function return_list_node(v,r)
 {
 var ret=
  {
  value: v,
  pointer: r
  };
return ret;
 }
console.log(return_list_node(10,return_list_node(20,null)));
```

but the issue remains. For example, the first call to return_list_node() will return `Object {value: 20, pointer: null}`.

If that helps, my main source of information is [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/). In this book, the author gives [a certain example](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#c_2uZIZgWSsu):

```
function randomPointOnCircle(radius) {
  var angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  return {x: radius * Math.cos(angle),
          y: radius * Math.sin(angle)};
}
console.log(randomPointOnCircle(2));
// → {x: 0.3667, y: 1.966}
```

And indeed, executing it in his site gives `{x: -0.2914551368496415, y: -1.9786495149985397}`. While if I run the above code locally, I receive `Object {x: 1.9649681395718306, y: 0.37269318543222546}`.

I have validated that in [this excersise](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#c_F73m7OkLk8) (in the sandboxed environment of the site) my code (used in `prepend()`) indeed returns what I expected it to return ( `{value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}` ), and not an Object.

Why the discrepancy between the sandboxed environment and my Google Chrome 48? What is the proper/expected behaviour of a function which returns an object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It does return exactly what you want - `console.log` don't show it that is all

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(return_list_node(10,return_list_node(20,null)));`

Comment: I validate that it is a console.log issue (the output formatting of the object).
Thank you all for your prompt clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9q4tpe8/) for your code in the question.

and an image of my chrome browser console below

[image]

idont understand, whats not working,  and now when i try from nodejs from a command line,  it print

```
{ value: 10, pointer: { value: 20, pointer: null } }
```

everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Console.log doesn't show nested objects sometimes. To get the full output, call

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
```

Answer (score 0):

It does that only what you expect. It is just console in google chrome shows it that way.
Try this:

```
x=return_list_node(10,return_list_node(20,null))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Function:

```
function return_list_node(v,r)
 {
 return {value: v, pointer: r};
 }
```

First Call:

```
return_list_node(20,null)  //returns Object {value: 20, pointer: null}
```

Second Call *(Now You are passing `{value: 20, pointer: null}`
)* as a second parameter which will obviously return :

```
 return_list_node(20,{value: 20, pointer: null}) //returns {value: 10, pointer: Object}
```